# Calling Swift function from Javascript in UrbanAirship message center details page

Tags: urbanairship.com

When the push notification is pushed from server side, the default Urban Airship message center is displayed on the app using

```
UAirship.defaultMessageCenter().display()
```

and tapping on the messages displays the message details. The content of message details page is an HTML payload which is part of the push notification triggered by server side. I need to call a swift function when a button on the WebView is tapped. Since we don't have access to the WKWebView presented in the view controller which is provided by UA, I am not able to call any swift function from javascript. Please suggest.

Comment: Have u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Urban Airship's [actions framework](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#actions) which can be used to trigger native code from a message center webview.

First, define your custom [UAAction](http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Classes/UAAction.html).

```
let swiftAction = UAAction(block: { (args: UAActionArguments, handler: UAActionCompletionHandler) -> Void in
    print("Action is performing with: \(args)")

    handler(UAActionResult.empty())
})
```

Then register the action after [takeOff](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#starting-urban-airship-services).

```
UAirship.shared().actionRegistry.registerAction(swiftAction, name:"swift_action")
```

You can then modify your HTML content to run the action from your message. Use the runAction method on the UAirship object which is inserted in the message center webview.

```
UAirship.runAction("swift_action", "arguments", function() {return true})
```

Additional resources:

- [Urban Airship Javascript Interface](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/custom-templates.html#urban-airship-javascript-interface)
- [Custom Actions](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios.html#custom-actions)